# Migraciones cambiaron varias columnas de otros modelos de tipo Integer a Bigint

Tags: base-de-datos, ruby-on-rails

Cree varias migraciones para agregar una columna de tipo booleano a un modelo, hacer un backfill y agregar un null constraint.

Corrí las migraciones y al revisar el `schema.rb` con `git diff` noté que en 5 tablas que no estan relacionadas con la que modificaba la migración, se cambiaron columnas (todas llamadas `cover_file_size`) de tipo `integer` a `bigint`.

No encontré un motivo por el cual esto pueda pasar de forma automática sin mi consentimiento.

Hay algún comportamiento default de Rails por el que pueda haber pasado esto?

Qué recomiendan? Dropear la DB y correr todas las migraciones de nuevo?

Comment: bigint tiene pros por sobre un simple integer, ¿este cambio afecta tu desarrollo?

Comment: Ojo que `schema.rb` se genera en base a lo que tengas en tu BD, por tanto si sale como bigint, es porque en tu BD la columna está con ese tipo. Ahora, por qué está así... ni idea, quizás corriste en algún momento migraciones creadas en otro branch por alguien más que trabaja en tu proyecto, quizás la versión del motor de DB se haya actualizado y maneje los atributos de otra manera, no se la verdad. De todas formas, si no afecta al funcionamiento de tu app, no creo que haya necesidad en que dropees.